# Confused about when to use int type or char type when passing a character into a function argument?

Tags: c, pointers, character

Currently in class we are learning about pointers, addresses and volatile for C. In one example, we have the following two functions that can be used to draw a character onto a VGA monitor using an Altera DE2 board.

For the following code, int character was used but my peers and I thought it should be char character since we are passing a character into the function argument.

```
void drawChar( int x, int y, int character )
{
    volatile unsigned char *pChar;
    pChar = getCharAddr(x,y);
    *pChar = ( character & 0x7f );
}


unsigned char *getCharAddr( int x, int y )
{
    y = max(0,min(MAX_Y_CHARS-1,y));
    x = max(0,min(MAX_X_CHARS-1,x));
    return (unsigned char *)(ADDR_CHARBUF + (((y<<MAX_X_CHAR_BITS)|(x))<<0));
}
```

Here is an example code to use the function drawChar:

```
drawChar( x, y, ‘D’ ); // draws ‘D’ at <x,y>!
```

Could anyone please explain why int was used here?

We were thinking it has something to do with the masking and having to get the binary values out of character... Although we are unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace the type of character with char you would receive the same results. A char, int, short, etc are all integral types. The person who wrote the function, would be the only one who could tell you why they chose int in this particular situation but you and your peers are correct that in general it is best to use a char as it represents the purpose of the data. Under the hood, that char may end up being promoted to an int anyway depending on the platform.